# Does AMD have open source graphics drivers for Windows?

Tags: windows, drivers, display-driver, open-source, amd-graphics-card

In the Linux world, AMD has been working very hard on AMDGPU recently, which is a high-quality open source driver now in the kernel. Does AMD have any similar open source drivers for Windows? What would it take for AMD to release great open source drivers for Windows?

Comment: So far as I know Linux drivers do not need to be certified. Windows Drivers must be certified by Microsoft so not much chance for open source Windows drivers at this point.

Comment: @John: perhaps not open source in the "compile from source" sense, but AMD *could* get their binaries certified and still release the source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does AMD have any similar open source drivers for Windows?

Open source AMD display drivers, that are compatible with Windows, does not exist.  Intel, AMD, nor Nvidia provide open source drivers for Windows.

Since the only GPUs on the market are from Intel, AMD, or Nvidia open source display drivers from those manufacturers do not exist on Windows.

> What would it take for AMD to release great open source drivers for Windows?

By default only signed drivers can be installed on Windows 8+.  In order to release open source drivers, AMD would have to release the source to their drivers, and provide signed compiled drivers.

It is not possible given the default configuration for the end user to compile their own display drivers on Windows.

Open source display drivers from AMD, that can be used on Windows, does not exist.  **AMD do not provide the source to their drivers on Windows.**

Comment: @SamAxe - Windows has a boot mode to handle driver developers.